# Notifications / Inbox aren't working on Security.SE and Bitcoin.SE

Tags: bug, global-inbox

My Security.SE and Bitcoin inbox notifications aren't working correctly.  I've had a few posts have new answers( that I have asked) and never received notification of the comment or the answer.

I'm not active on StackOverflow recently so I can't say if the issue applies here as well.

I used Chrome/Safari latest on OSX and Win7

(Edit: I have multiple browsers open on several machines at the same time.  Not sure if this is related, but it always worked in the past)

Comment: Notifs work on SO.

Comment: Yes I received this notification on one browser window that was focused on Crypto.SE.  No other notification worked for me so far

Comment: Also, I didn't receive this notification (new answer) posted 
in the past hour

http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17875/are-some-sts-token-formats-better-than-others-saml-vs-swt-vs-jwt